# Adding two inputs together inside a variable

Tags: jquery, math, var

G'day there,

I'm unsure of how exactly I can do this. Here's some code to provide some context.

```
// API dictionary
$(document).ready(function(){

    var itemNameTitle = 'Task'
    var itemQtyTitle = 'Quantity'
    var itemRateTitle = 'Rate <span>($/hr)</span>'
    var itemPriceTitle = 'Price <span>($)</span>'
    var itemNameInput = '<input type="text" name="item-name-input" value="Mockups">'
    var itemQtyInput = '<input type="text" name="item-qty-input" value="1">'
    var itemRateInput = '<input type="text" name="item-rate-input" value="35">'
    var itemPriceCalc = 128 / 2

    $('#page').load('templates/default.html', function() {

            $this = $(this);
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-name-title%',itemNameTitle));
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-qty-title%',itemQtyTitle));
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-rate-title%',itemRateTitle));
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-price-title%',itemPriceTitle));
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-name-input%',itemNameInput));
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-qty-input%',itemQtyInput));
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-rate-input%',itemRateInput));
            $this.html($this.html().replace('%item-price-calc%',itemPriceCalc));

    });

});
```

I hope you can see what I'm trying to do here. Basically I need the `value`s of `itemQtyInput` and `itemRateInput` to multiply together, then post to a div on the page. Unfortuntely, when I do this, it just ends up posting 'NaN'.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how can u apply division when itemRateInput is a string variable?

Comment: @NitinVarpe Could you please elaborate? I'm a beginner with jQuery.

Comment: There's no jQuery in your question. That's just plain, ordinary Javascript. You set two variables to character strings.

Comment: @Barmar I pulled it out of my full jQuery doc. I've posted the full code.

Comment: First in your previous code you seem to want a division, but your title suggest an addition but now you ask for a multiplication. Maybe what you are looking for is a soustraction...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this... I have tried this... it is working...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                var itemQtyInput = '<input type="text" name="item-qty-input" value="1">'
                var itemRateInput = '<input type="text" name="item-rate-input" value="35">'
                var itemPriceCalc = parseFloat(parseInt($(itemRateInput).val()) / parseInt($(itemQtyInput).val()));

                alert(itemPriceCalc);
                $('div').val(itemPriceCalc);
            });
```

Comment: Is there way of implementing this solution with the `keyup` event, so that when `itemQtyInput` or `itemPriceCalc` is changed, the answer will be changed on the page too? Hope this isn't too much to ask :S

Comment: @ Vishal: That will use temporary input elements, not the ones that the OP's code is putting on the page.

Comment: @JeremyBlazé: Yes, there is; my answer (and wrxsti's and barmar's) shows you how. Just put that code in the `keyup` handler.

Answer (score 3):

Once those elements exist in your page (so, after the `$("#page").load` callback), you can get jQuery objects for them like this:

```
var $qty  = $("input[name=item-qty-input]");
var $rate = $("input[name=item-rate-input]");
```

Then you can get their values via `.val` and parse those strings as decimal floating point:

```
var qty  = parseFloat($qty.val()); // Or a whole number: parseInt($qty.val(), 10)
var rate = parseFloat($rate.val());
```

Then of course, divide (or multiply or add or whatever it is you're actually trying to do):

```
var itemPriceCalc = rate / qty; // Or + or *
```

Typically you'd wait to do this for a user event, but I'm not quite sure what your page is up to.

Answer (score 0):

> String / String = Not A Number

Hopefully this makes sense:

```
var value1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('input1').value;

// parseInt converts the string to a integer
var result = parseInt(value1) / parseInt(value2);
```

Comment: *"String / String = Not A Number"* Actually, for division (and multiplication and subtraction and many other mathematical ops), JavaScript will coerce the type. `"4" / "2"` is `2`. Of course, if you use `+`, it'll concatenate, not add.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/dqsDp/)

You don't want to put the literal markup into the variable. You want to refer to what is called a selector:

```
var itemQtyInput = $('input[name="item-qty-input"]').val();
var itemRateInput = $('input[name="item-rate-input"]').val();
var itemPriceCalc = itemRateInput / itemQtyInput;
alert(itemPriceCalc);
```

Something to this effect should work. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery way to do what you want:

```
var qty = parseInt($("input[name=item-qty-input]").val(), 10);
var rate = parseInt($("input[name=item-rate-input]").val(), 10);
var product = qty * rate;
$("#resultDiv").text(product);
```